# Return rows that has 3 or more consecutive values as 1 with Order by on Date & Group By Region

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, analytics

I tried Tabibitosan method but no help. Can you please suggest some other solution for below scenario.

Using Oracle 11g:

Please find the below table format ,

```
Region  Date      Value
East    1/1/2018    1
East    1/2/2018    1
East    1/3/2018    0
East    1/4/2018    1
East    1/5/2018    1
East    1/7/2018    1
West    1/9/2018    0
West    1/10/2018   0
West    2/3/2018    1
West    2/4/2018    1
East    2/5/2018    1
West    2/8/2018    0
West    2/9/2018    0
West    2/10/2018   0
```

From the above table I should return the rows that has value 1 occurred 3 or more times with respect date(order by) and Region.

```
**My Output:**

    Region  Date       Value
    East    1/4/2018    1
    East    1/5/2018    1
    East    1/7/2018    1
```

Note : The date in the Date column may not contain all the days. Say, in the above 1/6/2018 is missing which is fine. I need to look for 'Value' column that has 1 consecutive for 3 or more rows when ordered by 'Date'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following if you wish to get all the rows which match the condition.

```
with data
  as (
select x.region,x.date1,x.value,x.pattern_start,x.rnk
 from (
select region
       ,date1
       ,value
       ,row_number() over(order by region,date1) as rnk
       ,case when value=1 
                    and lead(value,1) over(partition by region order by date1) = 1
                    and lead(value,2) over(partition by region order by date1) = 1
                   then row_number() over(order by region,date1)
        end  as pattern_start   
       ,lead(value,2) over(partition by region order by date1) as next_val_2
       ,lead(value,3) over(partition by region order by date1) as next_val_3
 from t)x
     )
select *
  from data y
 where y.rnk in (select pattern_start from data union all
                 select pattern_start+1 from data union all
                 select pattern_start+2 from data
                  )
order by 1,2
```

Demo Link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1aa6d5de2b0ec375f659d0243aba350a

Answer (score 1):

Just use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(value) over (partition by region order by date) as value_1,
             lead(value, 2) over (partition by region order by date) as value_2
      from t
     ) t
where value = 1 and value_1 = 1 and value_2 = 1;
```

In the event that you have 4 or more in a row and only want the first one, you can add a `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by region order by date) as prev_value,
             lead(value) over (partition by region order by date) as value_1,
             lead(value, 2) over (partition by region order by date) as value_2
      from t
     ) t
where value = 1 and value_1 = 1 and value_2 = 1 and
      (prev_value is null or prev_value <> 1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much I'm verifying your query. Will the first query return all the rows when there is consecutive 4 values?

Comment: @ABR . . . It would return the first two rows, because each begin a sequence of 3.